# Derivation of the Antoine equation

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

The vapour pressure $P^0$ of a pure substance can be approximated by a semi-empirical formula called the Antoine equation, which says $P^0$ is related to the temperature $T$:
$$ \ln(P^0) = A - \frac{B}{C+T} $$
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation) says it is derived from the Clausius-Clapeyron relation, which I suppose is just by combing it with the ideal gas law, where $ \Delta V_m = V_{m,g} - V_{m,l} \approx \frac{RT}{p} $, so that
$$ \left( \frac{dP}{dT} \right)_{evaporation} = \frac{\Delta L_m}{T \Delta V_m} \approx \frac{\Delta L_m p}{RT^2} $$
Integrate both sides and we get a form that looks very similar to the Antoine equation:
$$ \ln(P^0) = A -\frac{B}{T} $$

However, I do not understand why C is added in the denominator, nor could I find any satisfying explanation. [This](https://www.bjanaesthesia.org.uk/article/S0007-0912(17)45165-8/pdf) is one of the few papers I found discussing this, but it also does not mention this.

Comment: It is because the observed behavior is not that of an ideal gas.